# Jquery get value of a variable from a ajax-call and put it to a new function

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, transfer

im having problem with getting value of a variable from the ajax-call function **getRequest** and put it into function **test**, not sure how it works, any help is appreciated!

```
function test() {
    var out = getRequest().name; //problem
    console.log(out);
};
function getRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/nextdocument',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 11000, //vänta på svar från servern om ingen inläsning
        success: function(data) {
            var name = data.description;
            var price = data.price;
            console.log("read--> " + name + price);
            setTimeout(
                    'getRequest()',
                    1000
            );

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function test() {
    var XHR = getRequest();
    XHR.done(function(data) {
       var out = data.description;
       console.log(out);
    });
}

function getRequest() {
    var XHR = $.ajax({
        url: '/nextdocument',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 11000, //vänta på svar från servern om ingen inläsning
        setTimeout(getRequest, 1000);  //WHY
    });
    return XHR;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Thats what i wanted! setTimeout(getRequest, 1000); --> theres gonna be a get runs after every get request is finished

Comment: Okay, just don't do `setTimeout('enochannanfunksjon()', 1000);` as it evals the quoted text to run the function, do it like in my example, or if passing data, do `setTimeout(function() {enochannanfunksjon();}, 1000);` instead. Happy to help. Lycka till !

Comment: Just as a sidenote, as I'm still not getting it, you do realise that when a function calls itself, then calls itself, then calls itself, it will be an endless loop of Ajax calls, and it will multiply everytime the function is runned again by an external handler, like a click event etc.